# Mybatis Use generated keys for Batch Insert

Tags: java, mybatis

I have done batch inserting in Mybatis and it is working fine. But I'm not sure how to store the generated primary keys for each row in the bean class. Here is my code,

Mapper.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
    "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
    <mapper namespace="com.xxxx.sample.test.dao.TestDAO">
        <insert id="insertEmployeeList" parameterType="java.util.List">
            INSERT ALL
            <foreach collection="list" item="element" index="index">
                INTO EMPLOYEE (name) values (#{element.name})
            </foreach>
            SELECT * FROM dual
        </insert>
    </mapper>
```

Emp.java

```
public class Emp {
public Emp(int id, String name) {
this.id = id;
this.name = name;
}
private int id;
private String name;
public int getId() {
return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}
}
```

Employee.java

```
public class Employee {
private List<Emp> list = new ArrayList<Emp>();
public List<Emp> getList() {
return list;
}
public void setList(List<Emp> list) {
this.list = list;
}
}
```

In the above example Employee is the object to be persisted in database which contains list of Emp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `useGeneratedKeys="true" keyProperty="id"  keyColumn="id"` with your insert block.

i.e.

```
<insert id="insertEmployeeList" parameterType="java.util.List" useGeneratedKeys="true" keyProperty="id"  keyColumn="id">
INSERT ALL
  <foreach collection="list" item="element" index="index">
    INTO EMPLOYEE (name) values (#{element.name})
  </foreach>
</insert>
```

Why use `select` doing inside insert? Just wondering.

Comment: There is no need to write `keyProperty="id"`, as it is the default value of that option.

Comment: I tried as you say but get error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28453475/mybatis-getting-id-from-inserted-array-of-object-returns-error can you help?

Comment: @iJava: Sure but will probably take sometime. hope you are not in a hurry

Comment: @indyaah Thank you for answer. I still can't solve this problem. So I'm waiting....

Answer (score 0):

> But I'm not sure how to store the generated primary keys for each row
>   in the bean class.

If you want to map the generated primary key with your pojo then foreach inside the insert xml won't work. You'll have to write simple insert with useGeneratedKeys="true" and call it for each record that you want to persist.

I have given detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35555074/5733129)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing this problems using @Annotations.

The main point is to use "list" as param and call it in generated keys.
Also be sure of using @Insert as annotation.

```
 @Insert("""
                <script>
                INSERT INTO myTable (
                    value_x,
                    username
                    ) VALUES
                <foreach collection='list' item='item'  separator=','>
              ( #item.myValue, #{username} )
               </foreach>
               </script>
            """)
    @Options(useGeneratedKeys = true, keyColumn = "my_id_name_generated", keyProperty = "list.myNameVariableId")
    void insertAllObjects(@Param("list")List<Object> listObjects, String username);
```