# MyBatis: getting id from inserted array of object returns error

Tags: java, mybatis

I use mybatis 3.3.0-SNAPSHOT. I want to insert list of objects, and get id of every object. In interface I have:

```
public void createCore(@Param("cores")List<Object> cores);
```

In xml mapper I have:

```
<insert id="createCore" parameterType="java.util.List" useGeneratedKeys="true" keyProperty="id" keyColumn="id">
  INSERT INTO mytable (raz,dva,tri )
  VALUES
    <foreach collection="cores" item="core" separator=",">
     (#{core.raz}, #{core.dva}, #{core.tri})
    </foreach>
</insert>
```

And I get:

> #### Error updating database.  Cause: org.apache.ibatis.executor.ExecutorException: Error getting generated
>
> key or setting result to parameter object. Cause:
>   org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Parameter 'id' not found.
>   Available parameters are [cores, param1]

I tried and keyProperty="core.id" but get the same error.

How to fix it?

Comment: which DB are you using BTW?

Comment: @indyaah MySql. Thank you for help, I think I could rise this question for developers. See https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/pull/324

Answer (score 2):

This is issue is fixed in version 3.3.1

Comment: @TomaszGawel My issue was fixed after mybatis update and I use MySQL.

Comment: @maksIm Could you provide your code? (I mean, how you point the id property)

Comment: class CancellationModel {
    protected Integer id;
    protected Integer pmId;
}

query in xml mapper
<insert id="create" parameterType="java.util.List" useGeneratedKeys="true" keyProperty="id">
    INSERT INTO property_manager_cancellation_rule (
    pm_id, ......
    )
    VALUES (
    <foreach item="item" index="index" collection="list" open="" close="" separator="),(">
        #{item.pmId,jdbcType=INTEGER},
    </foreach>
    )
</insert>

I pass here a list of my objects with empty id field.
After insert I am able to get Id value from objects in my list.

Comment: @TomaszGawel sorry for a messy code above, I don't know how to format it. I guess the main moment is to set these values useGeneratedKeys="true" keyProperty="id".

Comment: @maksIm I have something very similar and it does not put generated id back into objects. The only differences are: 1. id type is Long not Integer, 2. i do not specify index attribute in foreach as i do not use it. 3. I have no empty open close attributes in foreach. 4. I heave getter and setter for id property which is private.

Comment: @TomaszGawel Hm, that is very strange, because after I did update mybatis from 3.3.0 to 3.3.1 everything started to work correctly.

Comment: @maksIm I found the reason. It is queer but the parameter passed to mapper (and listed in foreach tag collection) must be named "list". It must be hardcoded somewhere :/

Comment: @TomaszGawel Well yes, it should be named as "list" in your mapper interface with @ Param annotation. E.g. int create(@Param("list") List<String> modelList);

Comment: @maksIm But it is something strange if the name of passed param plays role. If you call it "aList" on both sides and `useGeneratedKeys` is enabled any other parameter name than "list" will cause exception thrown. But if `useGeneratedKeys` is disabled it will work with any parameter name.

Comment: @TomaszGawel Hm strange, useGeneratedKeys only means that primary key will be generated by database, and you should name an argument in interface only when you need to pass more than one value to a method in other case you wont be able to access an argument.

Comment: @TomaszGawel I'm facing the excatly same problem, however even I changed this name to 'list' it still throws me 'id not found' exception, I'm using mybatis 3.4.1

Comment: @Neeson.Z did you manage to solve your problem? If no maybe paste some code (maybe in  another question) then I could compare with my source and tell the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Got that error too while trying to insert multiple rows with usegeneratedkeys.

The workaround fix I found was mentioned here:http://mybatis-user.963551.n3.nabble.com/MyBatys-Batch-Insert-doubt-error-retrieving-generated-id-binding-to-POJO-td4029977.html

All you need is to rename the param to "list". so "cores" -> "list" in the example above, and auto generated ids are working.