# MyBatis useGeneratedKeys on insert throwing org.apache.ibatis.executor.ExecutorException

Tags: java, mybatis

I am using mybatis 3.4.4 with Oracle db. I want to insert an object and get the generated id of it. I have the code below for that purpose.
In mapper.xml:

```
<insert id="createAsset" useGeneratedKeys="true" keyProperty="asset.id" keyColumn="ID" parameterType="Asset">
```

In mapper interface:

```
Long createAsset(@Param("asset") Asset asset);
```

I get this error:

> org.apache.ibatis.executor.ExecutorException: Error getting generated key or setting result to parameter object. Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28453475/mybatis-getting-id-from-inserted-array-of-object-returns-error) question which is basically the same with mine and the author claims to have solved it by updating the version. I made sure that I have the latest version, still the problem persists.

Help, please?

Comment: Can you provide query and object POJO

Answer (score 0):

The bean structure and the given exception make me think MyBatis expects to find the "asset" field already filled with a "Asset" object instance, while it is null.

Furthermore, I think "parameterType" must indicate the type of the "id" field (maybe integer?), not the type of the field container (Asset).